# Can't use new node to collect existing nodes from TreeView in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, treeview

I have following function for **searching through the Treeview**:

```
public static TreeNode FindAllNamesInTreeView(TreeView treeView, String name, int StartNode = -1, bool Searchilds = true)
{
   TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode("SRes");
   newNode.Nodes.Add("Test");

   // check if we have a treeview
   if (treeView == null)
      return null;

   // iterate through the treeview's root nodes
   for (int i = 0; i < treeView.Nodes.Count; i++)
   {
      // for each root node try to find the node with the name we want
      TreeNode foundNode = FindNameInTreeView(treeView.Nodes[i], name, StartNode, Searchilds);

      // if we found the node, return it
      if (foundNode != null)
         if (TheIndexOf(foundNode) > StartNode)
            newNode.Nodes.Add( foundNode); //Error here!
   }

   // no node found
   return newNode;
}
```

On executing the newNode.Add(foundNode); I have the following **exception**:

'A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll'

Could anybody tell me what's wrong or how I can add collect all found nodes to one here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the same node to two trees.  Therefore, if you find one, and try to add it to `newNode`, you get an `ArgumentException`.

Instead of using a `TreeNode`, I would suggest returning a `List<TreeNode>` instead.

Comment: I want a collection of all nodes found.
In future I want to iterate through them to implement FindNext function.

Comment: Decision found - I'll use the list to store found elements: